# Network disconnects between 2 sites

Tags: networking

I have site A and site B.  They are connected essentially via ethernet by an ISP (the ISP uses a radio tower to create a point to point tunnel from A to B and basically provide me an ethernet hookup on both ends). Site A and B are on the same vlan (10.10.11.1/24) and all traffic from B routes through site A to reach the internet. I have an HP ProCurve 2910al at site A and an HP ProCurve 2824 at site B.  The two are connected to each other via this point to point ethernet link.  Site B has 5 workstations, 5 IP phones, 1 server, and I just installed a VMware host.  Site A has a 25+ workstations, phones, a few servers and printers.  The workstations and phones in site B work perfectly. However, I cannot get any VMs that are installed on the new host to be able to access the internet or even ping site B. I also cannot ping the switch in site B from site A or manage it from site A. However, if I do a "show cdp neighbors detail" command on the switch in site A, it sees the site B switch and the details and information about it.

So basically, everything local to site A works fine.  Everything local to site B works fine.  It's the connectivity for select devices between site A and site B that does not.

I thought it could be an issue with MDI/MDI-X, but both switches support auto negotiation and appear to be working. I brought both the switch and the host from site B to site A to test and when everything is at site A, everything works properly connected exactly as I have it. I believe there must be an issue in the point to point ethernet provided by the ISP. However, the ISP says that they do not do anything to the network traffic between the two points and I haven't been able to prove otherwise.

Does anyone have any other ideas of what could be causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

`The workstations and phones in site B work perfectly. - It's the connectivity for select devices between site A and site B that does not.`

If some devices work and others don't then it would appear that the problem is not at layers 1 or 2. If it is then you've got one very strange problem, but let's assume that you do not have one very strange problem. The problem then is at layer 3.

1. CDP/LLDP is a Data Link layer protocol (layer 2). The fact that you see neighbor information in both switches again confirms that layers 1 and 2 are OK.
2. The fact that you can't connect to the management switch in Site B and that your virtual machines in Site B can't connect to the network leads me to believe that you've got a layer 3 problem. Have you confirmed that the switch in Site B has an appropriate ip address and subnet mask? Have you confirmed the same for the virtual machines?

Comment: I definitely agree that this does not appear to be a layer 1 or 2 problem.  I have verified that the switch in Site B has a correct IP and the correct subnet mask.  I have confirmed the virtual machines have the correct IPs and subnet mask also. The subnet mask matches all the other devices that are working at site B.